# How do I retrieve information from UI thread?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm quite new at vb.net and using different threads so I don't exactly know how to use the invoke method. I basically want to assign selected_item as the one that user has selected in combobox from UI thread.

```
Dim selected_item As String
If ComboBox1.InvokeRequired Then
   selected_item = ComboBox1.Invoke(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
Else 
   selected_item = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
End If
```

I get the error cross-thread operation not valid. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `Invoke` you need to specify a method that gets invoked on the UI thread. If you want to get a value, that method has to return that value and then `Invoke` will return that same value on your secondary thread. In your case:

```vb
Private Function GetComboBox1SelectedItem() As Object
    If ComboBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Return ComboBox1.Invoke(New Func(Of Object)(AddressOf GetComboBox1SelectedItem))
    Else
        Return ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    End If
End Function
```

You can then call that `GetComboBox1SelectedItem` method on any thread and it will return you the currently selected item.

If you call that method on a secondary thread, `InvokeRequired` is `True` and execution enters the `If` block. In that block, the `Invoke` method creates a delegate, marshals it to the UI thread and invokes it. That delegate is for the same method, so it gets executed a second time. The second time, we're on the UI thread so `InvokeRequired` is `False` and execution enters the `Else` block. In that block, the `Selecteditem` is retrieved and returned. The `Invoke` method then returns the value returned by that second instance of the method and that gets returned by the first instance.

You might like to read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387) for a more rigorous explanation of how to build such methods and what they actually do.

Answer (score 1):

Little bit shorter

```
Dim selected_item As String
If ComboBox1.InvokeRequired Then
   selected_item = ComboBox1.Invoke(Sub() ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
Else
   selected_item = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
End If
```

Comment: Should that not be `Function` rather than `Sub`?

Comment: Also, if this is part of code known to be on a secondary thread then the `If...Else` is unnecessary and simply `Dim selected_item = CStr(ComboBox1.Invoke(Function() ComboBox1.SelectedItem))` would suffice.